# Sitecore MVC 3 - alias or friendly url

Tags: sitecore, alias, friendly-url

We are running Sitecore.NET 6.3.0 with MVC 3. I have this url :
https://test.mydomain.dk/myprivate/my-page/my-page/my-page/

The corresponding tree structure looks like this.
Sitecore > Content > Portal > Home > myprivate > my-page > my-page > my-page

Instead of showing the above url, I would like to show https://test.mydomain.dk/myprivate/my-page, when the user is standing at the position mentioned in the above tree structure.

Is there an easy way to do this, (read: without coding) that is a method that can be done within the sitecore cms backend itself.
I want the "editors staff" to be able to do this by themselves.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik the only way to do something like this is to use an Alias.

The alias would be:

https://test.mydomain.dk/my-page (ie. missing the myprivate) but should work.

Otherwise you're gonna have to do some coding of some sort.

Comment: Ok I have tried to create and alias and named it my-page had it link to the last my-page node. When testing this at a browser I still see the same url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Sitecore Alias.
This is configurable per item in the Presentation ribbon -> Aliases

You may use slashes in your alias, so "myprivate/my-page" would be a valid alias.

Comment: Ok I have tried to create and alias and named it my-page had it link to the last my-page node. Afterwards I move to the last my-page node and click the presentation tab and add my-page. When testing this at a browser I still see the same url.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias to do this, however you will likely need to override the `LinkProvider` to have that new URL rendered to the front-end:

1. Create an alias like "myprivate/my-page" to point to your sub-page
2. Override the LinkProvider with this Sitecore Shared Source LinkProvider: `http://svn.sitecore.net/LinkProvider/Trunk/Links/LinkProvider.cs`

The summary of this new `LinkProvider` is:

> Link provider to override the default with logic to, depending on
>   configuration,  apply the `Rendering.SiteResolving` setting, apply aliases for
>   items where they exist, and append a slash character  to URLs that have no
>   extension.

The key being **"[...] apply aliases for items where they exist"**.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your comments. I tried multiple ways, but without success. I have given up on this.